# SQL query in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I have two tables: `Category (Id, Name, ...)` and `Question (Id, CategoryId, Title, ...)` with relation `Category 1-* Question`. I need to get the top three categories (with the highest number of questions) from the database.
I wrote this SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 c.Name, COUNT(q.CategoryId)
FROM Category c
JOIN Question q
ON c.Id = q.CategoryId
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT(q.CategoryId) DESC
```

and of course it works, but I need to write this query in LINQ. The main problem is in the first line with `COUNT`. How should I use it in this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where your data comes from but the query will look something like

```
var q =
    from c in categories
    join q in questions on c.Id equals q.CategoryID
    group c by c.Name into g 
    orderby g.Count() descending
    select new
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    };

 q = q.Take(3);
```